# Equivalent definitions of Lebesgue integral

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

In "The Elements of Integration & Lebesgue Measure" by Bartle (1st Edition), the Lebesgue integral of a non-negative $\Sigma$-measurable function $f: \Omega\to\mathbb{R}^*$ is given by (p. 30)
\begin{align}
    \int f = \underset{\varphi\ \le\ f}{\text{sup}}\int \varphi
\end{align}
where $\varphi$ is a non-negative simple function.

On the other hand, in "Introduction to Measure and Integration" by Taylor (1st Edition), the Lebesgue integral of a non-negative $\Sigma$-measurable function $f: \Omega\to\mathbb{R}^*$ is given by (pp. 111-112)
\begin{align}
    \int f = \lim_{n\to\infty}\int \varphi_n
\end{align}
where $(\varphi_n)$ is a sequence of non-decreasing non-negative simple functions converging to $f$ (i.e. $0 \le \varphi_n \le \varphi_{n+1}$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\varphi_n = f$).

Are these two definitions equivalent? If so, how does one show it (ideally without invoking Fatou's lemma)?

Comment: See the proof of the Monotone Convergence Theorem [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Proof_4).

Comment: The proof on MCT only shows that the first definition implies the second definition. For equivalence, we will need to show that the second definition implies the first as well; how does one do that?

Comment: Part of using second definition is to prove that the limit is independent of the choice sequence $(\varphi_n)$.  Then it is just a matter of using $\mathbb{R}^*$ is first countable to extract a countable cofinal subnet $(f_n)$ in the poset $\{\varphi\leq f\}$ and hence a nondecreasing subsequence $\varphi_n=\max_{m\leq n} f_m$.